# Rendering Hierarchy based on data using Object.entries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am having a object that looks like the following:

```
export const data = {
  "Category 1": [
    {
      key: "1",
      label: "Applications",
      children: [
        {
          key: "3",
          label: "Browser",
          children: [
            {
              key: "4",
              label: "Mozilla",
              children: []
            },
            {
              key: "5",
              label: "Firefox",
              children: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Category 2": [
    {
      key: "2",
      label: "OS",
      children: [
        {
          key: "6",
          label: "Windows",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

This should basically draw a tree with two entries with `Category 1` and `Category 2` and its children should be drawn recursively.

```
Category 1
   ---- Applications
          --- Browser
                --- Mozilla
                --- Firefox
Category 2
   ---- OS
          --- Windows
```

This should be dynamically rendered. The number of first level objects will be determined using the number of keys of the object. I have tried with an array of objects and it works. But when I am having it in the above format, I am unable to render it as a tree. Help would be greatful.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-zsxsxh?file=/src/Tree.js

When I am trying it with `treeData` it works, but with `data` inside constants.js it doesnt work.

```
import React from "react";
import TreeNode from "./TreeNode";

const Tree = ({ data = [] }) => {
  return (
    <div className="d-tree">
      <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
        {data.map((tree) => (
          <TreeNode node={tree} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tree;
```

I tried with `Object.entries` to render the tree, it doesnt work

Comment: recursive component is a way to go

Comment: Can you give each node in`data` the same format?  Eg: `[{key: 1, label: 'Category 1', children:[children of cat 1]}]`?  You could transform your data to this format with object.entries(data).map(…)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-gvslnw?file=/src/Tree.js

Comment: actualy its not much different from the answers provided as well. but i can post an answer

Comment: @cmgchess Thanks. Also I want the first level item to have some custom css. Only to the first level. May be you can some color to that first level item

Comment: @cmgchess thanks . I tried your code   by adding an input that can be used as search box. I was able to search it across the tree, Is it possible to have the tree open when I find the matching item.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could write the `Tree` component like this and pass down the key (`category`) and the value (`items`) of `Object.entries` as props to `TreeNode`

```js
const Tree = ({ data = [] }) => {
  return (
    <div className="d-tree">
      <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
        {Object.entries(data).map(([category, items]) => (
          <TreeNode
            key={category}
            node={{ label: category, children: items }}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the `TreeNode` you can recursively render `TreeNode` components based on if it has children or not. [Here](https://dev.to/knowit-development/recursive-components-in-react-37ka) is a resource on that.

Also you can add styles only to the first level.
I used a prop called `level` and defaulted it to 1, then I give styles only if the level is 1 (used inline styles for simplicity). For the next levels, I increment the level prop by 1.

```js
const TreeNode = ({ node, level = 1 }) => {
  const [childVisible, setChildVisiblity] = useState(false);
  const hasChild = node.children && node.children.length > 0;

  const nodeStyle = level === 1 ? { fontWeight: "bold", color: "red" } : {};

  return (
    <li className="d-tree-node border-0">
      <div className="d-flex" onClick={(e) => setChildVisiblity((v) => !v)}>
        <div className="col d-tree-head" style={nodeStyle}>
          {node.label}
        </div>
      </div>

      {hasChild && childVisible && (
        <div className="d-tree-content">
          <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
            {node.children.map((item) => (
              <TreeNode key={item.key} node={item} level={level + 1} />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </li>
  );
};
```

```js
const data = {  "Category 1": [    {      key: "1",      label: "Applications",      children: [        {          key: "3",          label: "Browser",          children: [            {              key: "4",              label: "Mozilla",              children: []            },            {              key: "5",              label: "Firefox",              children: []            }          ]        }      ]   }  ],  "Category 2": [    {      key: "2",      label: "OS",      children: [        {          key: "6",          label: "Windows",          children: []        }      ]    }  ]};

const TreeNode = ({ node, level = 1 }) => {
  const [childVisible, setChildVisiblity] = React.useState(false);
  const hasChild = node.children && node.children.length > 0;

  const nodeStyle = level === 1 ? { fontWeight: "bold", color: "red" } : {};

  return (
    <li className="d-tree-node border-0">
      <div className="d-flex" onClick={(e) => setChildVisiblity((v) => !v)}>
        {hasChild && (
          <div
            className={`d-inline d-tree-toggler ${
              childVisible ? "active" : ""
            }`}
          >
           {'>'}
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="col d-tree-head" style={nodeStyle}>
          {node.label}
        </div>
      </div>

      {hasChild && childVisible && (
        <div className="d-tree-content">
          <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
            {node.children.map((item) => (
              <TreeNode key={item.key} node={item} level={level + 1} />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </li>
  );
};

const Tree = ({ data = [] }) => {
  return (
    <div className="d-tree">
      <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
        {Object.entries(data).map(([category, items]) => (
          <TreeNode
            key={category}
            node={{ label: category, children: items }}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};


const TreeList = () => {
  return <Tree data={data} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<TreeList />, document.querySelector('.app'));
```

```css
.d-tree-container {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.d-tree-node {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
}

.d-tree-toggler.active {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='app'></div>
```

[image: Edit React Hooks Counter Demo (forked)]

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` structure is different from `treeData`, although the children are in the same format.

Instead of an object at the top-level:

```js
export const data = {
  "Category 1": [ ... ],
  "Category 2": [ ... ],
};
```

you should have an array with `key`, `label` and `children`:

```js
export const data = [
  {
    key: "Category 1",
    label: "Category 1",
    children: [ ... ]
  }, ...
];
```

If you really can't edit the `data` (it's right there ...) you could map the top-level entries using the property name as `key` and `label`:

```js
const dataAsArray = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) =>
  ({ key, label: key, children: value })
)
```

**Added in response to comment**

If that's your preferred input format then you could put the data conversion into your `Tree` component:

```js
const Tree = ({ data = [] }) => {
  const trees = React.useMemo(() => (
    data instanceof Array
      ? data
      : Object.entries(data).map(
          ([key, children]) => ({ key, label: key, children })
      )
  ), [data]);
    
  return (
    <div className="d-tree">
      <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
        {trees.map((tree) => (
          <TreeNode node={tree} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: yes thats right.  I am trying to draw the same using `data` .I need help to draw the tree with `data` as its input.

Comment: @lrr97 Answer modified to include a snippet to massage the data from the current format

Comment: I think `Tree` would be a better place to do that. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In tree.js you can validate if data is not an array and transform it:

`Tree.js`

```js
const Tree = ({ data = [] }) => {
  if (!(data instanceof Array)) {
    data = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
      return { label: key, children: data[key] };
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="d-tree">
      <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
        {data.map((tree) => (
          <TreeNode node={tree} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-3hxcgq